# left header placeholder in sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

In Sitecore SXA How i create a left header placeholder as shown in the below image do i need create a custom grid layout and custom grid css

[image]

Comment: Did you try using row splitter and then adjust the grid size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the toolbox in SXA, you need to first add the `Splitter (Columns)` component like this.

[image]

Then on each column use the Edit Style and open the grid.

[image]

And adjust the style.

[image]

Then for the Bottom use the `Splitter (Rows)`

It will show the same structure that you need like this.

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Sxa provides `Row splitter` and `Column splitter` for splitting the pages.

You can add row splitter first and in the first row again add col splitter and specify the column count for ex: 4 and 8 columns.

Later, add the required rendering in the first column and other rendering in next column as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page splitters to generate additional columns or rows inside the header, content, or footer containers.
There are two types of splitters:

- **Column splitters** – generates divs with proper grid classes wrapped by the row container. Grid values specify the column widths.

```
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='grid-6'></div>
      <div class='grid-6'></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

- **Row splitters** – generates empty row divs that fill the full width of the available parent container.

```
    <div class='row'></div>
    <div class='row'></div>
    <div class='row'></div>
```

You can add classes for both columns and rows. You can also mark specific splitter sections and style them differently than the other sections. This can be useful for styling a page part that breaks the grid system. However, you can only override grid behaviour for specific rows.